# Factory Pattern Linker Error undefined reference in c ++

Tags: c++, oop, factory-pattern

I want to use abstract factory pattern.  But in the contructor of Factory there is an error and it says

```
    `[Linker error] undefined reference to `DbDatabaseFactory::CreateConnection()'`    
     [Linker error] undefined reference to `DbDatabaseFactory::CreateCommand()' 
    `[Linker error] undefined reference to `DbDatabaseFactory::CreateConnection()'`    
     [Linker error] undefined reference to `DbDatabaseFactory::CreateCommand()'
```

Here is my code:

```
class IConnection{

      public:
              bool Connect();
              bool Disonnect();
              bool connectionState;
      };

class ICommand{
      public:
              void  Execute(string);
      };

class SqlDbConnection: public IConnection{

      public:
             bool connectionState;
             bool Connect(){
                   connectionState = true;
                   cout << "MS Sql bağlantısı açılacak";
                    return true;
                    };
             bool Disonnect(){
                     cout << "MS Sql bağlantısı kapatılacak";
                     return true;
                     };
      };

class MySqlDbConnection:public IConnection{

      public:
             bool connectionState;
             bool Connect(){
                  connectionState = true;
                  cout << "MYSql bağlantısı açılacak";
                  return true;
                  };
             bool Disonnect(){
                 cout << "MYSql bağlantısı kapatılacak";
                  return true;
                  };
      };

class SqlDbCommand: public ICommand{
      public:
             void Execute(string command){
                   cout << "Sql Command çalıştırılıyor";
                   };

      };

class MySqlDbCommand: public ICommand{
      public:
             void Execute(string command){
                   cout << "MySql Command çalıştırılıyor";
                   };
            };

class DbDatabaseFactory{
      public:
             IConnection CreateConnection();
             ICommand CreateCommand();
      };

class MsSqlDbFactory: public DbDatabaseFactory{
      public:
             IConnection CreateConnection(){
              SqlDbConnection sqlConnection;
              return sqlConnection ;
             }

             ICommand CreateCommand(){
              SqlDbCommand sqlCommand;
              return sqlCommand ;
             }
      };


class MySqlDbFactory: public DbDatabaseFactory{
      public:
             IConnection CreateConnection(){
              MySqlDbConnection mySqlConnection;
              return mySqlConnection ;
             }

             ICommand CreateCommand(){
              MySqlDbCommand mySqlCommand;
              return mySqlCommand ;
             }
      };

class Factory{
              DbDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;
              IConnection _connection;
              ICommand _command;
      public:
              Factory(DbDatabaseFactory);

           void Start(){
               _connection.Connect();
                if(_connection.connectionState == true){
                _command.Execute("SELECT ...");
                }
          };


      };

Factory::Factory(DbDatabaseFactory dbFactory)
{
    _databaseFactory = dbFactory;   
    _connection = dbFactory.CreateConnection();
    _command = dbFactory.CreateCommand();
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You should read up on the `virtual` keyword in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration of DbDatabaseFactory should have been,

```
  class DbDatabaseFactory{
  public:
         virtual IConnection* CreateConnection() = 0;
         virtual ICommand* CreateCommand() = 0;
  };
```

And also in the Factory class, you should keep pointers or references to DbDatabaseFactory,IConnection and ICommand to employ `runtime polymorphism` properly.

Please find the following changes to Factory class,

```
 class Factory{
          DbDatabaseFactory* _databaseFactory;
          IConnection* _connection;
          ICommand* _command;
  public:
          Factory(DbDatabaseFactory*);

       void Start(){
           _connection->Connect();
            if(_connection->connectionState == true){
            _command->Execute("SELECT ...");
            }
      };


  };

  Factory::Factory(DbDatabaseFactory* dbFactory)
  {
      _databaseFactory = dbFactory;   
      _connection = dbFactory->CreateConnection();
     _command = dbFactory->CreateCommand();
  }
```

These changes should solve your problems.

Also modify your `MsSqlDbFactory` as below

```
class MsSqlDbFactory: public DbDatabaseFactory{
  public:
         IConnection* CreateConnection(){
          return new SqlDbConnection();
         }

         ICommand* CreateCommand(){
          return new SqlDbCommand(); 
         }
  };
```

Comment: There is error on Factory constructors. It says cannot convert `IConnection' to `IConnection*' in assignment and cannot convert `ICommand' to `ICommand*' in assignment

Comment: @cagin Sorry I made a mistake in the previous answer. your DbDatabaseFactory should be returning pointers to IConnection and ICommand. I have done the modifications.. Also you should change MsSqlDbFactory to return pointers..

Comment: It works thank you. But I have another error right now in main method. I have undefined reference to IConnection::Connect() and undefined reference to ICommand::Execute(std::string). Here is my codes:
 MsSqlDbFactory* msSQlFactory = new MsSqlDbFactory();
    Factory* factory = new Factory(msSQlFactory);
    factory->Start();
Do you have suggestion about it?

Comment: Its the same issue as with `DbDatabaseFactory` class you had initially. You need to make functions in `IConnection` and `ICommand` pure virtual by adding `virtual` keyword in the front and `= 0` at the end of function declaration in both IConnection and ICommand. Right now you have declared a function, but its definition is missing.